# aptana freezes when creating a project on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: macos, aptana

I cannot use aptana on my mac pro 1.1 with OSX Lion. Aptana freezes when I try to create any project. Reinstalling didn't help.

Btw plugin for eclipse is working.

Does anyone have similar issue?

Comment: So, to confirm:

1. Install Aptana Studio Standalone
2. Create new Web Project
3. Studio freezes?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes! But when I force quit Aptana and manually delete workspace folder, Aptana launches with no problems. Otherwise when workspace folder is not removed, relaunching Aptana causes freeze.

Comment: And it will freeze no matter what type of project you create? What happens if you import an existing project?